# Install persistent cli command in GCP kubernetes cluster

Tags: shell, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, cluster-computing

Im trying to install Velero in a Kubernetes cluster on GCP, I have successfully installed it the first time but every time I logged back to the GCP shell the command is not available anymore, (as if the installation disappeared), I still can see my velero backups tho when I install it again

How can I persistently install any utility?

Comment: Any changes that you make to the container image will be lost when the container is relaunched. This means you must modify the container image during creation, not at runtime. There are exceptions such as container mount points that persistent files.

Comment: How did you install it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that Cloud Shell VM is ephemeral and is turned down when you are not using it interactively. See the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#custom_installed_software_packages_and_persistence) below:

> The virtual machine instance that backs your Cloud Shell session is
> not permanently allocated to a Cloud Shell session and terminates if
> the session is inactive for an hour. After the instance is terminated,
> any modifications that you made to it outside your $HOME are lost.

Also, I am not sure how exactly you have installed Valero in your GCP cluster but you might find [this guide](https://medium.com/@ct.ics2009/install-velero-with-helm-in-gcp-15b7a0186ae) useful. It shows how to install Velero with HELM in GCP, step by step.